# Is Dotenv still a necessary package with 6.x.x Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

I recently set up a simple project with a .env file and called the env variables in my code with process.env.[variable  name] and it totally worked without adding the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package to my project.

Has node incorporated this natively?  I tried googling but it didn't turn up any useful information so I am kind of confused.  Thought it would be easy to confirm or deny.

Here is my 'app':

```js
// Load the SDK and UUID
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');

// Create an S3 client
var s3 = new AWS.S3({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
});

// Create a bucket and upload something into it
var bucketName = 'node-sdk-sample-' + uuid.v4();
var keyName = 'hello_colorado.txt';

s3.createBucket({Bucket: bucketName}, function() {
  var params = {Bucket: bucketName, Key: keyName, Body: 'Coloradoical!'};
  s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err)
      console.log(err)
    else
      console.log("Successfully uploaded data to " + bucketName + "/" + keyName);
  });
});
```

And my package.json (without dotenv):

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "aws-sdk": ">= 2.0.9",
        "node-uuid": ">= 1.4.1"
    }
}
```

Just a thought, could it be related to the fact that I am running my application from the command line with `node simple.js`?  If so, can you explain why?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, and I use `.env` files in almost every project I work on. I think there might have been something else in play when you thought it was working without adding the package.

Comment: hmm I would be inclined to believe you, but my 'app' is v. simple.  Will post the entirety of it above along with my package.json

Comment: Make sure you don't have any environment variables defined globally, or in a terminal launching application, as well. Can't speak for you, but _I've_ definitely made that mistake before.

Comment: it is not installed or built with node you have to install package for `env` to run

Comment: Does `node -p 'process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'` print `undefined` or does it print your access key? If it prints your access key, then you have the environment variables set in your shell and the `.env` file is irrelevant. (You can confirm if that's the case by removing the `.env` file and seeing if it still works.)

Comment: It prints `undefined`... so weird how this is working. @Trott

Comment: How about if you `console.log()` the value of `process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` in your `simple.js` file? Still `undefined` or does it then show your access key? If still `undefined`, then your S3 auth is happening some other way or perhaps not at all.

Comment: Ah, that's it.  It must be because I have my credentials in the aws command line?  The environment variables are still undefined in the js file. @Trott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Node.js does not read `.env` files automatically.

Possible explanations for what's going on:

- Perhaps the environment variable you are using is already set in your shell before you run the program.
- Perhaps your AWS credentials are being stored/utilized some other way by your machine. (Based on our comment conversation, this looks like the case for you, but I'm including other things to generically help others who might be seeing something similar.)
- Perhaps one of the modules you are loading is reading the `.env` file.

---

Suggested additional info from @maxwell:

AWS CLI help pages indicate that the precedence for configuration values is:

- command line options
- environment variables
- configuration file

So sounds like the information was coming out of a configuration file for @maxwell.

Comment: Yep - the second one is the answer.  Perhaps add this line I just found from the aws cli help pages to your answer.  

`
   Precedence
       The above configuration values have the following precedence:

       o Command line options

       o Environment variables

       o Configuration file
`

Comment: Added the info, thanks. Take a look and let me know if I messed it up somehow.

Comment:  looks great to me.

Answer (score 0):

I also hit the case that .env was read into process.env "automatically", which puzzled me a lot. I then found out it was because I install a zsh plugin called [dotenv](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/dotenv) which will automatically load ENV variables from .env file when you cd into the directory.