# .env variables not available in jest testing environment

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, environment-variables, ts-jest

When I run my code normally I can access my .env file with `const newVar = process.env.MY_DOTENV_VARIABLE`, but when I run jest everything becomes undefined. Is this normal for jest? If so, what is the best practice for storing variables?

Is it simply to create a set up file, eg:

```js
// jest.config.ts
  setupFiles: [
    "<rootDir>/.jest/setEnvVars.ts",
  ],
```

```
# .env
  MY_DOTENV_VARIABLE=exampleString
```

Comment: How did you load environment variables from `.env` file?

Comment: I think I was getting confused and I'd actually been setting the variables with cli/scripts. Silly error on my part. I think I just needed to install dotenv.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to install dotenv. I think I got confused where process.env was working previously without the `dotenv` packaging. This was either due to me setting the env variables with scripts in my package.json file, eg `"scripts":"NODE_ENV=test ..."` and/or some packages were making changes. (I'm using various `aws` packages, and [I've read that they can change environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41148836/11664580))